# Time comparison in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, comparison

I want to check whether the current time is in between 10AM and 10PM. How can I do the check?

Comment: It is considered good form to include the code you wrote, explaining the problem you encountered. Not doing so makes it sound like you are fishing for answers without having done the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a `Range` and check for the inclusion.

```
(10..22).include?(Time.new.hour)
# => true
```

Your code will be

```
if (10..22).include?(Time.new.hour)
  # do whatever you want
end
```

Comment: Don't you think using `<` and `>` is a better solution, because `include` would internally use searching, whereas we just need to check if its within the bounds. i.e. if you have a sorted array and you want to find out if an entry exists, then you just check the outer bounds instead of searching the whole array.

Comment: 1.9.3 has Range#cover? to avoid @Swanand's objection.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
time = Time.new
if time.hour >= 10 && time.hour < 22
    // Your code
end
```

More info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm

I never used the Ruby language, but if you just google it, it will be in 1 of your first results how to get the current hour.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `between?`?

```
d1 = Time.new(2011,11,18,10)
d2 = Time.new(2011,11,18,22)

[
  Time.new(2011,11,18,9),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,12),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,23),
].each{|d|
  p d.between?(d1,d2)
}
```

Results in

```
false
true
false
```

As an alternative, you must create the from-to-time based on your testtime:

```
[
  Time.new(2011,11,18,9),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,12),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,23),
].each{|d|
  d1 = Time.new(d.year,d.month,d.day,10)
  d2 = Time.new(d.year,d.month,d.day,22)
  p d.between?(d1,d2)
}
```

Based on this, you may extend `Time`:

```
class Time
  def between_hours?( h1, h2)
    d1 = Time.new(year,month,day,h1)
    d2 = Time.new(year,month,day,h2)
    self.between?(d1,d2)
  end
end

[
  Time.new(2011,11,18,9),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,12),
  Time.new(2011,11,18,23),
].each{|d|
  p d.between_hours?(10,22)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this for future reference: (JRuby 1.6.7, ruby 1.9.2-p132)

```
require 'time'
require 'benchmark'

s= Time.parse("2012-04-12 11:00")
m= Time.parse("2012-04-12 11:30")
e= Time.parse("2012-04-12 12:00")

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
    bm.report { 10_000.times{ (s..e).include?(m) } } # slow!
    bm.report { 1_000_000.times{ (s..e).cover?(m) } }
    bm.report { 1_000_000.times{ m.between?(s, e) } }
end
```

Yields (amd64 x4 core archlinux)

> ```
>   user     system      total        real
> 2.390000   0.000000   2.390000 (  2.389000)
> 0.342000   0.000000   0.342000 (  0.342000)
> 0.153000   0.000000   0.153000 (  0.154000)
> ```